# pymssql: access data in cursor without for loop

Tags: python, sql, pymssql

I am retrieving a single row from a single column in my database.  The pymssql documentation exclusively uses loops to access the data in a cursor.

```
conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, "tempdb")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT %s', 'Foo')

#This works but it's ugly
for row in cursor:
    print row[0]
    break

#The following throws an error
print cursor[0][0]

conn.close()
```

Is there a way to access the data inside the cursor object without a `for` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cursor.fetchone()[0]` in place of `cursor[0][0]`.

However, if nothing is returned from the query you're going to get an exception. Better to do something "ugly" like this:

```
row = cursor.fetchone()
if row:
    print row[0]
```

Comment: Perfect.  Looks like they updated their docs too.  It's the first example on this page... http://pymssql.org/en/latest/pymssql_examples.html    In my use case there should always be data returning from the table in question.  If the table has no rows then raising an exception would be the desired behavior.